# Trying to install gem ferret for gem treat but cannot build native extensions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, installation

I can normally install native extensions on my Windows 8 system with BitNami Rubystack Ruby 1.9.3p448.  Rubystack comes with DevKit integrated.  However, I cannot get ferret and other treat dependencies to build.  The errors look like compile errors, not make errors.

While I am specifying ferret in this context, several gems required by treat are experiencing these same errors, exactly.  So, it must be a systemic problem.  In fact, I located exactly the same issue occurring in GNUstep circa 2008 that was "fixed in svn".  To this point, I have been unable to identify that fix.  That conversation occurs [HERE](http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?func=detailitem&item_id=22653).

On ferret, I've tried version 0.11.8.5, 0.11.8.4 and even 0.11.6 each getting basically the same errors as listed here.  I've looked for alternatives like sdsykes-ferret but it seems currently unsupported from what I can tell.  The current ferret active fork appears to be [HERE](https://github.com/jkraemer/ferret).  Again, the problem is systemic, affecting several treat prereqs.

As these are dependencies of gem treat NLP, so I really don't want to consider non-PnP alternatives especially since several are breaking.  I am having to go through them one by one to get them up.  Treat tries to dynamically install them but doesn't lock version, either.  I hope it will work...

My latest ferret attempt to install follows.  It is just the latest iteration of several attempts.  Searches in SO have found similar problems that were pretty old and I've already attempted them.

```
D:\BitNami\rubystack-1.9.3-12>call gem install ferret --version "0.11.8.5" --platform=mswin32 -- --with-ruby-include=D:\
Users\Richard\Downloads\Ruby\ruby-1.9.3-p448
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions with: '--with-ruby-include=D:\Users\Richard\Downloads\Ruby\ruby-1.9.3-p448'
This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing ferret:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    D:/BitNami/rubystack-1.9.3-12/ruby/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb --with-ruby-include=D:\Users\Richard\Downloads\Ruby\ruby-
1.9.3-p448
creating Makefile

make
generating ferret_ext-i386-mingw32.def
compiling analysis.c
compiling array.c
compiling bitvector.c
bitvector.c: In function 'frt_bv_eq':
bitvector.c:54:5: warning: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code
compiling BZLIB_blocksort.c
compiling BZLIB_bzlib.c
compiling BZLIB_compress.c
compiling BZLIB_crctable.c
compiling BZLIB_decompress.c
compiling BZLIB_huffman.c
compiling BZLIB_randtable.c
compiling compound_io.c
compound_io.c: In function 'cmpdi_read_i':
compound_io.c:136:9: warning: unknown conversion type character 'l' in format
compound_io.c:136:9: warning: unknown conversion type character 'l' in format
compound_io.c:136:9: warning: too many arguments for format
compound_io.c: In function 'cw_copy_file':
compound_io.c:325:9: warning: unknown conversion type character 'l' in format
compound_io.c:325:9: warning: too many arguments for format
compound_io.c:334:9: warning: unknown conversion type character 'l' in format
compound_io.c:334:9: warning: unknown conversion type character 'l' in format
compound_io.c:334:9: warning: too many arguments for format
compiling document.c
compiling except.c
except.c:23:37: warning: initialization discards qualifiers from pointer target type
except.c:24:29: warning: initialization discards qualifiers from pointer target type
compiling ferret.c
compiling field_index.c
field_index.c: In function 'string_handle_term':
field_index.c:237:23: warning: operation on 'index->values' may be undefined
compiling filter.c
compiling fs_store.c
fs_store.c: In function 'fso_seek_i':
fs_store.c:252:9: warning: unknown conversion type character 'l' in format
fs_store.c:252:9: warning: format '%s' expects type 'char *', but argument 4 has type 'long long int'
fs_store.c:252:9: warning: too many arguments for format
fs_store.c: In function 'fsi_seek_i':
fs_store.c:306:9: warning: unknown conversion type character 'l' in format
fs_store.c:306:9: warning: format '%s' expects type 'char *', but argument 4 has type 'long long int'
fs_store.c:306:9: warning: too many arguments for format
fs_store.c: In function 'fsi_length_i':
fs_store.c:322:5: warning: implicit declaration of function 'fstati64'
fs_store.c: In function 'fs_store_new':
fs_store.c:431:17: warning: unused variable 'stt'
compiling global.c
global.c: In function 'frt_vstrfmt':
global.c:190:23: warning: assignment discards qualifiers from pointer target type
global.c: In function 'signal_to_string':
global.c:412:14: error: 'SIGBUS' undeclared (first use in this function)
global.c:412:14: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
global.c: In function 'frt_init':
global.c:436:22: error: storage size of 'action' isn't known
global.c:443:5: warning: implicit declaration of function 'sigemptyset'
global.c:446:5: error: storage size of '__old' isn't known
global.c:446:5: warning: implicit declaration of function 'sigaction'
global.c:446:5: warning: unused variable '__old'
global.c:447:5: error: storage size of '__old' isn't known
global.c:447:5: warning: unused variable '__old'
global.c:448:5: error: storage size of '__old' isn't known
global.c:448:5: warning: unused variable '__old'
global.c:449:5: error: storage size of '__old' isn't known
global.c:449:5: error: 'SIGBUS' undeclared (first use in this function)
global.c:449:5: warning: unused variable '__old'
global.c:450:5: error: storage size of '__old' isn't known
global.c:450:5: warning: unused variable '__old'
global.c:436:22: warning: unused variable 'action'
make: *** [global.o] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in D:/BitNami/rubystack-1.9.3-12/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ferret-0.11.8.5 for inspe
ction.
Results logged to D:/BitNami/rubystack-1.9.3-12/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ferret-0.11.8.5/ext/gem_make.out

D:\BitNami\rubystack-1.9.3-12>
```

Any fix for this nightmare?

Comment: Ferret gem is actually not [actively developed](https://rubygems.org/gems/ferret), 2 new versions in 7 years. I suggest you to use thinking_sphinx

Comment: What I am trying to do is get treat running, not ferret.  Ferret is simply embedded.  Also, the correct current fork for ferret is https://github.com/jkraemer/ferret, so there is relatively current work on it.  Thanks.

Comment: Added a lot of additional information and clarified it as a systemic problem beyond ferret for treat prereq's in preparation for the bounty...

Comment: But, just had a thought about using the sdsykes-ferret updates to patch ferret.  That wouldn't fix the systemic issue though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to seemingly insurmountable problems installing prerequisite gems, I am abandoning treat and moving to an alternative.  Right now, I am looking at open-nlp because it is a current Ruby wrapper to the OpenNLP project.  I'd prefer NLTK since it is the gold standard, but no Ruby wrapper exists as of yet that I can find.

This is only an issue for treat under Windows, IFAIK, and even then only due to the prereqs.  I've seen nothing that says treat isn't wonderful in other environments.